# Find the darkest region in the sky

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I have a dataset of billions of points (stars) scattered on a two dimensional plane (sky), each with its corresponding (brightness) value.

How can I efficiently find locations for a fixed size rectangle (corresponding to a telescope field of view) for which the point values sum up to a minimum?

Comment: 1) How familiar are you with [segment trees](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html) and scanline (e.g. https://chowdera.com/2022/139/202205191601406413.html)? 2) I assume that the data can fit in the main memory. Moreover, you have enough space to fit multiple copies of this data (I need around 5 copies, I think). Is it true? 3) The running time is $O(n \log n)$, which for $n=10^9$, by a rough estimate, can take around an hour (it could be wrong by a factor of 10 in either direction). Is it acceptable?

Comment: @Dmitry, If *p* is the number of points in a region, *n* is the total number of points, and *p* is much less than *n*, wouldn't the order simply be *O(n)*? ¶ e.g. the lower left corner of a region can be in almost *n* different locations, and calculating the brightness of each region is order *p* (a small constant).

Comment: @RayButterworth 1) `lower left corner of a region can be in almost n different locations` - a region can be defined by 2 points, not one (e.g. a point on the left side and on the top side). So, in your notation, it'll be $O(pn)$, I think. Whether it's better than $O(n \log n)$, depends on the value of $p$, I guess. 2) `calculating the brightness of each region is order p` - how do you do this?

Comment: @Dmitry, I was assuming the region rectangles don't rotate, in which case one point will define the location. ¶ Isn't the brightness of a region simply the sum of the *p* brightness values within that region?

Comment: 1) This is my assumption as well. You may need two points to define an optimal region (one on the left or right side, and one on the top or bottom side). I guess you conjecture that it suffices to consider rectangles such that one of their corners is a point, and this is not true. 2) How do you find the points within the region efficiently?